# ASP.NET website looks different on IE10

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net website that looks good, as it should, on IE9 as well as the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.
For some reason, the site doesn't look right on IE10. The fonts get too big, html tables with columns set to 'no wrap' get wrapped, etc.
Clicking IE10's "Compatibility button" doesn't help. Font sizes might get back to normal, but other issues arise, such as, images or menus out of place, etc.
I've tried overriding the compatibility mode, to no avail:

```
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=9” />
```

What else can I do?

**EDIT:** Found a solution. Applied the hotfix described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: can't you write code in your html markup that handles Styles as well as setting the font that way..?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. You should start with poking at the developer tools in both IE9 and IE10 to find out where the problematic font sizes are coming from.

Comment: It is not just an issue with 'fonts'...

Comment: Just start with the fonts, one thing at a time?

Comment: What's the url of your site? What about IE settings itself (zoom)?

Comment: To all the @#$*!'s out there: This was a valid question. The solution was to apply the hotfix described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty broad question, but I suggest you take each of your problematic elements, one by one and check their compatibility for IE10 using the following website:

[Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)

It contains compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more in desktop and mobile browsers. I suggest you use something like the Firefox Web Dev Toolbar add-on to inspect your page elements:

[Toggle Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/toggle-web-developer-toolbar/)