# Unable to get IE10 to match Chrome and Firefox display

Tags: asp.net, css, cross-browser

I have an asp.net 4.0 application that I'm trying to balance for all three browsers. The content lines up as it should for Firefox and Chrome, but when displaying in IE10 the text elements become substantially larger and no longer flow within their layout correctly. Oddly enough, IE8 displays correctly, as does IE10 in Compatibility Mode, but using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/> 
or 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE8"/>
```

has no effect (using it as the first element in the head.)

There's a hotfix for asp.net 4.0 that adds the user agent for IE10 (without which IE10 was displayed in basic mode), but that seems to have been replaced by a Windows Update that seems to have already been applied (the hotfix installation is blocked as a result.) This issue is described here, [ASP.NET website looks different on IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503267/asp-net-website-looks-different-on-ie10) .

At this point I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue. Here's a picture of the difference, with the Chrome appearance above IE10 to give a comparison:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBEUw.png

Both browsers are in zoom 100% mode, but IE10 is clearly making everything larger.

Here is the code and CSS for the displayed segment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Commitment Details</title>
<link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
</head>
<body>
  <form runat="server">
  <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" EnableModelValidation="True" GridLines="Both" CssClass="Formview">
    <ItemTemplate>    
    <label style="width:auto">Commitment Workseet For:</label> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblPageInfo" runat="server" CssClass="Right"/>       
    <ol class="header">
      <li><label style="font-weight: normal;"><%# Eval("cus_name") + "#" + Eval("cmt_cusno") %></label></li>
      <li><asp:Button id="btnNextPage" runat="server" Enabled="false" Style="background-image: url(images/greyrightarrow.png)" CssClass="arrows" /></li>
      <li><asp:Button id="btnPrevPage" runat="server" Enabled="false" Style="background-image: url(images/greyleftarrow.png)" CssClass="arrows" /></li>
      <li><asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Selection List" CssClass="Right" OnClientClick="location.href='Selection.aspx'; return false;" /></li>
      <li><asp:Button ID="btnHelp" runat="server" Text="Help" CssClass="Right" OnClientClick="location.href='docs/CWDocumentation.doc'; return false;" /></li>
      <li><asp:Button ID="btnUpdateCmt" runat="server" Text="Update Commitment" CssClass="Center" 
          OnClientClick="window.open('UpdateCommitment.aspx','_blank','height=310,width=630,scrollbars=0,location=no,toolbar=0,menubar=no'); return false;" /></li>
    </ol>
```

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
body 
{
  width: 768px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:small;
}
.SelectionView
{
  text-align: left;
  border-style: none;            
}
.Formview
{
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-color: #999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  color: black;
}
.Center
{
  float: right;
  margin-right:50px;
}
.Right
{
  float: right;
}
.arrows
{
  float: right;
  width: 36px;
  height: 24px;
}
.header 
{
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  clear:both;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.header li 
{           
  display: inline;
  line-height: 2em;
}
li 
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

Any suggestions on what I should be looking at next, or ideas for a solution?

Comment: Have you tried adding the viewport meta and setting initial scale? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> No idea if this will help at all, but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: @tomca32 I doubt the problem is mobile specific, but if it was, the viewport meta tag would do nothing because IE doesn't support it.  It uses the `@viewport` rule:  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/ and http://timkadlec.com/2012/10/ie10-snap-mode-and-responsive-design/

Comment: @tomca32 cimmanon is correct. This is not a mobile issue (and it displays correctly on an iPad anyway.) I did try it just out of curiosity no effect (the viewport version cimmanon suggested.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emulating the version `(IE=EmulateIE8)` tells the browser to use the doctype to determine how to render content. Pages without a doctype will be rendered in [quirks mode](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/doctype/a/aaquirksmode.htm). Using the html5 doctype, though, switches almost any browsers to `content standards mode`. **And this is why your code probably fails**!

In most cases this line does the job :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

When Internet Explorer comes across this line it will change the engine that is being used to first Chrome Frame, if the plugin is installed, and then to Edge (the highest supported document mode of the browser).

> Any website running on an Intranet will run in Compatibility Mode and any website on Microsoft’s [Compatibility List](http://www.validatethis.co.uk/tag/compatibility-list/) will change to it as well.

**If you sill get issues, you better check if something inside your css may cause this 
browser-incoherence!**

---

**Edit (added some css hints)**

I'm just gonna list a few things that could go wrong in your css in order to reproduce the unexpected result! I'm not able to test those, so unfortunately I'm not gonna tell you any specific property to change to make it work right out of the box! I'll just write down a few things based on the images you attached to the question!

> What seems different at least to my eyes, is the font-weight, alignment and eventually the font-size on buttons!

Hence you are using ordered-lists and buttons I'm 99% sure this will solve your particular problem straight away (but hey it's internet explorer, nobody ever knows)!

```
ol li { text-align:left }

button { font-size: 100%; font-weight: normal }
```

If it does, great... but keep on reading in order to prevent things like that to happen again!

If it doesn't :

- Some browsers when rendering in quirks mode recreate some legacy behavior where tables (but this could apply to other elements as well) do not inherit properly as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Fixing_Table_Inheritance_in_Quirks_Mode)!
- Every css property you are not overriding in your file could potentially have a different default value on each given browser! There is a commom practice to use css reset templates like [Eric Meyer’s](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), and many others (here's a little [collection](http://sixrevisions.com/css/a-comprehensive-guide-to-css-resets/))! All they do is to reset some crucial css properties leaving an equal ground to build upon!
- Based on my previous point, stating `font-size:small` or `font-weight: normal` could be interpreted in different ways, without any property-reset! `small` is not a cross-browser font sizing unit!

Here's a little hint of what you could try in order to make it work, not all of the proprieties are needed, of course, but i hope you figure them out trying :

```
html, body { font-size: 100%; font: inherit }

body { line-height: 1 }

ol li { text-align:left }

button { 
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    *vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
    *overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that line had no effect. All of the CSS used by the page is in my original post. I don't see anything that should be problematic, but I'm not particularly experienced with CSS and may be missing something.

Comment: the above CSS didn't do the trick--any of it--but you were right on the money in regards to font-size: small not being a cross-browser standard. When I set the font size to 9pt the display elements became consistent across all three browsers I tested. I'll have to do some reading on the reset stuff, I've come across it before but haven't tried using it. I really need to do some studying up on CSS as I definitely have a use for it. :)

Comment: @Ben i'm really glad you found the solution :) As i said, there was no way for me to test the code on this computer!